# 'RegDeleteTree' not declared // Compilation error

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm trying to delete a windows registry key and all its subkeys, specifically the 'Open with SHCP' key (which I created) and all its subkeys and values. I have the code, but it throws me this error:

```
'RegDeleteTree' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HKEY hKey;

    cout << "Deleting Tree:\n\n";
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Classes\\*\\shell", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey)== ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Successfully opened key\n";
        if(RegDeleteTree(hKey,"Open with SHCP") == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << "Successfully deleted the key\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Failed to delete the tree\n";
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, no tree available\n";
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Windows 7 and Dev-C++ 5.6.3. 
Also, I'm able to use other functions like `RegOpenKeyEx` and `RegCreateKeyEx`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the SDK for Vista or later, and you need to set `_WIN32_WINNT` :

```
#define  _WIN32_WINNT  0x0600
#include <Windows.h>
```

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa379776(v=vs.85).aspx) for `RegDeleteTree`:

> To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0600 or later. For more information, see Using the Windows Headers.